# Use Firebase Cloud Function for Create User(Remove Automatically Login When register user)

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When user register from client side(mobile app) , user automatically login app i dont want auto login so, I did some research, I had to use a firebase cloud function to solve this.

But I get a few errors when calling the function , how can i fix these errors

**First error :**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://***.cloudfunctions.net/createUser' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**second error :**

zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST https://****.cloudfunctions.net/createUser net::ERR_FAILED

**Third Error**

core.js:4197 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://***.cloudfunctions.net/createUser", ok: false, …}

**Firebase Console log**

2:02:23.363 ÖS
createUser
Function execution started

2:02:23.390 ÖS
createUser
Function execution took 28 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

**cloud function :**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
  if (request.method !== "POST") {
      response.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  } else {
      let body = request.body;

      const email = body.email;
      const password = body.password;
     

      admin.auth().createUser({
          email: email,
          emailVerified: false,
          password: password,
      })
      .then((userRecord) => {
          return response.status(200).send("Successfully created new user: " +userRecord.uid);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          return response.status(400).send("Failed to create user: " + error);
      });
  }
})
});
```

**client side :**

```
 signUp(email,password){
    let body = {
      email : email,
      password : password
    }
     this.http.post(
        'https://****.cloudfunctions.net/createUser',
      body
      ).subscribe(a=>{console.log("Work")});
}
```

**EDIT (new cloud function code) :**

1st and 2nd bug fixed 3 still continues but I can create users.

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ' POST, OPTIONS');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
   if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
     res.end();
  }
   else {
    
      let body = req.body;
      console.log(body.email)
      console.log("body.password")
      const email = body.email;
      const password = body.password;
     

      admin.auth().createUser({
          email: email,
          emailVerified: false,
          password: password,
      })
      .then((userRecord) => {
          return res.status(200).send("Successfully created new user: " +userRecord.uid);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          return res.status(400).send("Failed to create user: " + error);
      });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross origin error has many reason, first problem is your current url that probably like a ads url, please change the url pattern and clear browser cache. If you are using a VPN turn off it. The Chrome blocks url that contain ads url. This problem is not happen on production environment.
If your problem not fixed with top solution, use chrome in security disable mode.
Open start menu and type `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` and
make sure that this headers set in your backend

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Request-Method:*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,token, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: please fix cros error, then comment new issue

Comment: please add headers in your backend. Is there a problem with Mozilla?

Comment: Based on your answer, I wrote them into the function, now the function is working, but the 3rd error still continues.